# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php

This is the html when I inspect element in chrome

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Please Wait</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ajax-loader1.gif" type="image/x-icon">
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="autoSubmit();" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
        <div>  
            <p class="header">Please Wait... Your Payment Request is being processed......</p>
           <p class="image_style">
               <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">       
           </p>       
           <ul>    
               <li>This is a secure payment gateway using 256 bit SSL encryption</li>        
               <li>When you submit the transaction, the server will take about 1 to 5 seconds to process, but it may take longer at certain times </li>
               <li>Please do not press "Back" or "Refresh" buttons</li>
           </ul>        
        </div>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Card Request</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function autoSubmit()
          {
              document.card_processing.submit();
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm posting some values to a url given and from there it is redirected using the below auto-submitting. Sometimes this page wont load sometimes it does.What is the problem?

This is what I get from console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
```

Comment: document.card_processing.submit(); is the problem. You're calling submit on card_processing which doesn't exist. What is card processing?

Comment: Wild guess, `document.card_processing` is undefined ?

Comment: I would expect to see a hidden form, but i dont..

Comment: Its loaded on the link where Iam posting my datas.But this works or doesnt works sometimes.

Comment: It should work when there's a form named `card_processing`, and fail when there isn't.

Comment: Why is ` <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Card Request</title>` inside `body` tag?

Comment: Could you please explain where `card_processing` comes from? Is this form name?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL See the control after the curl is executed is not on my side..The form genrated and autosubmit stuffs are created by the other side and i have no control over it.But what is making me confused is,it sometimes works fine and sometimes doesnt!

Comment: Could you please add `curl` stuff in your question also?

Comment: Are you loading this HTML code in its own window or do you append it to an already existing element of your document? Show us the code you use to get this HTML and the code you use to present it to the browser.

Comment: So you are fetching this html from a remote site using curl in php, and then doing what? dumping it straight into the browser?

Comment: Also, seriously, how has this question gotten no downvotes or votes to close? I'm afraid to since it has survived 4 years and I think I'm missing something. Is that the general consensus? Do any of us believe at this point that the OP will update this question with further info or select an answer already provided?

Answer (score 0):

replace your code by adding a form:

```
<body onload="autoSubmit();" cz-shortcut-listen="true">

  <form name="card_processing">

    <div>  
          <p class="header">Please Wait... Your Payment Request is being processed......</p>
          <p class="image_style">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">      
          </p>        
          <ul>    
            <li>This is a secure payment gateway using 256 bit SSL encryption</li>        
            <li>When you submit the transaction, the server will take about 1 to 5 seconds to process, but it may take longer at certain times </li>
            <li>Please do not press "Back" or "Refresh" buttons</li>
         </ul>        
    </div>

  </form>
```

---

but i think you need a redirection page which shows a progress status:

for achieving that there is no need for a form or any scripting on body load

use meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; ,URL=<redirect_url>">
```

this will redirect the page after 5 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dealing with javascript to submit your form:

So it's wisely to **wait** until your ***script is loaded***.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
});
```

[For more detail.](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript#plainjavascriptreadyalternative)